# CSS Link hover not for images

Tags: html, css

I have a scenario where I want to have the text links with border-bottom, and set-up the css like this

```
a:hover {
color: #492512;
border-bottom: 2px dashed #94705A;
}
```

The problem is that the images that are wrapped in links also have this border-bottom, eg.

```
<a href="home">
  <img src="logo.jpg" alt="Logo" class="logo-img">
</a>
```

How can I target the a:hover that it is only for text links? Pure CSS would be preferable.

Comment: With pure CSS you need to mark that `<a>` tag with a classname: `<a class="image-link"><img></a>` and then make `a:hover:not(.image-link) { border-bottom: 2px dashed;`

Comment: Are you able to change the html markup?

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude I tried that, it doesn't work for me .. something I missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No problem.

Add a class to your text links. Then target those links like this.

```css
a.testing:hover {
  color: #492512;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #94705A;
}
```

```html
<a href="home">
  <img src="http://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/sprites.svg?v=bc7c2f3904bf" alt="Logo" class="logo-img">
</a>

<a class="testing" href="home">
  TESTING
</a>
```

Hope this helps.

---

Added with EDIT

Here is Another Option

```css
a:hover {
color: #492512;
border-bottom: 2px dashed #94705A;
}

a[href*='ignorethis']  {
 text-decoration: none !important;
 border-bottom: 0 none !important;
}
```

```html
<a href="http://www.milk.com?ignorethis">
  <img src="http://s.w.org/style/images/wp-header-logo.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-img">
</a>


<a href="http://www.milk.com">
  TESTED
</a>
```

This achieves the same thing by targeting target all anchors whose href attribute contains the given value ('ignore this'). Other ways this can be used.

attribute *= contains value

attribute ^= begins with value

attribute $= ends with value

To use this just append '#special-test-value' to the end of the link or in the case of a targeted link append '?special-test-value=0' or in the case where the query string already exists use '&special-test-value=0'

I thought this was an interesting way to target links and that it might be new to a lot of people.

---

Another use case

If the case is that a single url or a specific set of urls you could use them to end target them and exclude the anchored images that way.

```
a[href$='somedomain.com/url1/'],  a[href$='somedomain.com/url2/'], a[href$='somedomain.com/url.../'], a[href$='somedomain.com/urlN/']  {
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border-bottom: 0 none !important;
}
```

OK that's it have a great night.

Comment: Thanks. it could also be a solution, but I better added a class to the images, I think it is clearer in my case (less image links on the site)

Comment: May I suggest you roll back your 2 edits, they are really messy solutions even if they do solve some rare requirements, and keep only the first, which by the way probably is the best answer of all, +1 from me.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways, either wrap the text in a `span` (below sample) or set a unique class to links with text only.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  color: #492512;
}
a:hover :not(img) {
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #94705A;
}
```

```html
<a href="home">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/50/100/" alt="Logo" class="logo-img" />
</a>

<br>
<br>

<a href="home">
  <span>Text</span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that pure CSS global styling doesn't work, so I resorted to jQuery to add a class to anchors which have images, like this:

```
jQuery("a").each(function(){
if ( jQuery(this).children('img').length > 0 ) {
jQuery(this).addClass("noborder");
}
});
```

And the CSS is:

```
a:hover {
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #94705A;
}

a.noborder:hover {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Thanks for all the comments and suggestions.

Cheers!

Answer (score -3):

Well you can make a separate class for image links:

```css
a:hover {
  color: #492512;
  border-bottom: 2px dashed #94705A;
}
a.image-anchor:hover {
  border-bottom: 0 none;
}
```

```html
<p><a href="stackoverflow.com">Text link</a></p>
<p><a class="image_anchor" href="stackoverflow.com"><img src="https://blog.stackoverflow.com/images/wordpress/stackoverflow-logo-300.png"></a></p>
```

Comment: Yeah, that could be one solution, but it is a bit clumsy for a CMS generated site. I thought also about a jQuery solution which simply adds a class to all <a>s which have an image, and then target that, if no pure CSS solution is possible.

Comment: This still generate a border bottom on the image link, which it shouldn't